# Server sided form validation where no scripts can be injected

Tags: javascript, php, regex, oop, preg-match

We're working on a school project which is a sign-up form we used htmlspecialchars to avoid script injections but we don't want the script to even be inserted into the database we thought about using regex but we can't get it to work at the moment we're using regex to verify the phone numbers and postal codes but can't seem to find out how we are going to make the regex so that there is no possible way to insert scripts into our database

here is an example of our preg_matches hopefully someone out here could help us.

```
    $postcode = false;
if (preg_match('/[1-9]{4}[A-z]{2}/', $_POST['Pcode'])){
    $postcode = true;
}

if ($postcode == false){
    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger float-left col-md-4\">
                 <strong>Niet gelukt!</strong> Deze postcode is niet geldig.
            </div><br><br><br><br>";
}
$mobiel = false;
if(preg_match('/(^\+[0-9]{2}|^\+[0-9]{2}\(0\)|^\(\+[0-9]{2}\)\(0\)|^00[0-9]{2}|^0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\-\s]{10}$)/',$_POST['TelNummer'] )){
    $mobiel = true;
}
if ($mobiel == false){
    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger float-left col-md-4\">
                 <strong>Niet gelukt!</strong> Dit mobiele nummer is niet geldig!.
            </div><br><br><br><br>";
}
```

Comment: *"we don't want the script to even be inserted into the database"* ... HTML is perfectly harmless in the database, just escape it when outputting it to the browser is all. You *could* use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to kill it altogether I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for reacting we will put some research into strip_tags()

Comment: `[A-z]` matches more than only letters. I guess you want `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: If you don't want any HTML code in your database you could simply remove it all with a simple regex : preg_replace("/<[^>]+>/im", "", $_POST['Pcode']);